# Getting error on MainActivity.java when running react-native run-android

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm running `react-native run-android` and I'm getting this error when compiling.

> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.)
>
> MainActivity.java:37: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>       @Override
>       ^
>   1 error
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I really don't know how to proceed so any suggestion is really welcome.

I have installed:

- javac 1.8.0_101
- react-native-cli: 1.0.0
- react-native: 0.32.0

**EDIT**

This is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "netbeast";
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether dev mode should be enabled.
     * This enables e.g. the dev menu.
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    /**
     * A list of packages used by the app. If the app uses additional views
     * or modules besides the default ones, add more packages here.
     */
    @Override  **//This is the line 37 where the error occurs**
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new UdpSocketsModule(),
            new RNNetworkInfoPackage()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the line 37 in mainActivity.java that the compiler is complaining.

Comment: I have added the mainActivity.java file ;)

Comment: Which line is 37? I don't think I see 37 total lines in your code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running react-native upgrade, this will update the mainActivity.java.